# Can bad weather be reason for Visa overstay

Tags: visas, overstaying

Weather is always unpredictable and there can easily be a situation where its last day of visa and transport is shut due to bad weather.

In such a scenario, you will not able to leave the country and in worst case you might struggle to reach airport which may lead to overstaying.

Is this illegal and can it impact future visa process?

P.S: Main focus of my query is Schengen visa but yes any general applicable rule would also help